# Error: Unknown named module "react-native-webrtc" when imports peerjs module

Tags: react-native, webrtc, peerjs

I'm facing a complex error when import react-native-peerjs module to any file in React native project. I just tried everything, but nothing works. Can you help me?
That is the error.

Error: Unknown named module "react-native-webrtc"

This is the step-by-step if someone wanna test.

npx react-native init teste
.
yarn add react-native-webrtc
.
cd ios && pod install
.
cd ..
.
yarn add react-native-peerjs
.
npx react-native run-ios
.
import Peer from 'react-native-peerjs' in App.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On `metro.config.js` located at the root folder of the app, changing the `inlineRequires` to `false` should do the job.